# Which statement is correct if I want to combine the given two statements in compact form?

Tags: notation

I have these two statements:\

(i).  If $A>0$, the left object touches the right object for $B>0$

(ii).  If $A<0$, the right object touches the left object for $B<0$

How can I write these statements in a compact form in only one statement? Which one of these is correct?

1. If $A>0$ ($A<0$), the left (right) object touches the right (left) object for $B>0$ ($B<0$).
2. If $A>0$ ($A<0$), the left (respectively, right) object touches the right (respectively, left) object for $B>0$ (respectively, $B<0$).
3. If $A>0$ (respectively, $A<0$), the left (respectively, right) object touches the right (respectively, left) object for $B>0$ (respectively, $B<0$).

Comment: all three options are far more confusing than writing out (i) and (ii) separately.

Comment: The first statement is correct as I've seen that notation used quite frequently in many course books.

Comment: Agree with @MatthewTowers. Compact writing is a minor goal; clear writing is the major goal. We should write with such clarity that a reader can get the meaning from a single read of the sentence (not going back and reading it multiple times). I would almost never use these hard-to-read constructions, especially when simply writing the two versions is extremely clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I write these statements in a compact form in only one statement?

You need to make explicit how the two objects depend on A and on B. Also, it's not clear from the original statements that 'touch' is not a symmetric relationship, which your 3 options suggest.

Without further context, "if the nonzero reals $A$ and $B$ have the same sign, then the left and right objects touch each other" is to me the most reasonable 'compactification', but from your 3 options I'm guessing that this is not what your original statements *actually* mean.

> Which one of these is correct?

Option #1 is the clearest. I don't think options #2 and #3 are correct, because when specifying a correspondence between two lists, the word "respectively" should appear only once.